# What does security "patching" mean, and why is it difficult?

Tags: linux, security

I just got to learn to manage a server, and got my first VPS running. As you may think, it's a "personal" training server, not running for any company.

I keep hearing about "security patching" and a lot of talks about how it's difficult that some people are not doing it, favoring other aspects over security.

I can't help but to think I'm doing something wrong by just activating a firewall and blocking all ports but the ones I'm using, and just initiating "`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y`" every now and then. (Note: I have a "rolling release GNU/Linux distro")

I know how ignorant I sound now, but is that not "patching"? If not, then please explain the concept of "security patching", goals that we want to accomplish through patching, some methods of patching as examples, and some difficulties faced by sysadmins as examples.

Note:
To limit the scope of this question, I'm specifically asking about the concept and practice of "security patching", not the more broad "hardening of systems".

Comment: If you want a secure server, your choice of a rolling release disto is most likely a very bad idea. Because you'll always get the latest releases of everything, which includes lots of new features. That's not the only reason why rolling releases are hardly ever a good choice for professional usage. Another aspect is the reliability of tools and tool chains which one relies on for productivity. If you really want to learn something, I'd suggest you switch to a distribution which focuses on rubustness / security.

Comment: The 'difficulties' in (security) patching don't usually start showing up until you have a production server (or MANY servers), that's in use, running third party software, and services. Imagine that you're running a LOB app that your company depends on.  There is a new security patch for the OS or another piece of software on the server.  You apply it, the LOB app is incompatible with the changes the patch makes for some reason, and stops working.  Now your employees are sitting there twiddling their thumbs because you just took out the application they need to do their jobs.  Sound easy? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a personal system up-to-date is relatively easy: as you say, usually doing a regular full upgrade of the system through the package manager is sufficient.  (Note that many people don't do this, however.)  The real problems come about in a large production setup.

In a corporate world, you may be managing hundreds of computers, rather than just one or two.  You have third-party software installed on some of these systems that isn't available through the repos, and you might also be compiling your own software that similarly isn't available in repos.  These combine to make it much more difficult to know what software is installed on your systems, whether there are any security vulnerabilities in known installed software, and how to push out updates across the fleet.

Additionally, every update is a change, and change brings risk.  While a little bit of downtime on your VPS is fine, at a company a bad update can cost millions of dollars.  Thus, every update has to first be tested to ensure that things all still work.

Let's add onto that another layer: the security fixes only go into a version of the software that you can't run because some other business-critical software doesn't support the new version.  Now you've got to try and backport a security fix in software you don't really know (dangerous!) while harranging a vendor to update their software (which they'll probably do in 10 years), assuming they're still around and not bankrupt by now.

In short, multiplying the scale and penalties makes it much more of an issue.

Comment: That's awesome! Really puts things into perspective for someone who doesn't work in tech fields. I just realized I had a software on my own PC (not even the VPS), that I compiled from source long ago and forgot about it; really outdated, lol! Just deleted it. Too bad you can't "just delete stuff" from employees PC's.

Answer (score 3):

Patching itself is simply modifying a system for a specific purpose (ie a gaming patch to increase or decrease difficulty). This can be something as trivial as changing a few lines in a script to replacing entire software components. Wikipedia's opinion differs slightly:

> A patch is a piece of software designed to update a computer program or its supporting data, to fix or improve it.[1] This includes fixing security vulnerabilities[1] and other bugs, with such patches usually called bugfixes or bug fixes,[2] and improving the usability or performance. Although meant to fix problems, poorly designed patches can sometimes introduce new problems (see software regressions)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28computing%29

With regards to security patching, this is normally done at a software level. The developer fixes his software's vulnerabilities, the new version enters the software ecosystem where:

- Packagers et al ready it for their distributions and it eventually makes its way back to the user (usually downloaded via a package manager.
- It is downloaded from the developer's website.
- It is shipped on storage media (or was once upon a time).
- The vendor of the product for which it is a component releases the update via any of the above methods.

In security-oriented patching, the goals are pretty obvious: security. In other words less exploits for the enemy. By enemy, I mean people *and* malicious software.
As pointed out in the comment by Class Stack, a rolling release is a terrible idea for security. With new features, come new bugs. Bleeding edge is better kept for non-critical use (ie your home gaming PC, not your company server). I would therefore highly recommend you go with the Debian Stable branch (I'm presuming you're using some distro based on Testing/Sid).
Debian's branches work like this (over-simplified):

- Stable - Has been in Testing for ages and no bugs have been found since forever.
- Testing - Stuff from Sid that's been tested and fixed. It all seems to to be working but there are never any guarantees.
- Sid - Newfangled stuff that's barely crawled out of the Experimental phase. It works, but expect the unexpected.

As for performing updates, I recommend the following:

- Always do an `apt-get update` before new software installations.
- Check the available upgrades before doing them. It's not necessary to upgrade unless there are security updates or you need the latest version of a software.
- You don't need to do a dist-upgrade unless you're upgrading the entire system to a new version, for example, wheezy to jessie. You should not issue this command lightly.

Regarding your current distro, if you decide to change to Stable (which you should), you will have to reinstall your system. Do not try to mix thing up or roll back or anything like that. A Debian install is fairly quick and painless, even from the net installer CD.

Hopefully this very overly-simplified overview helps you with a basic understanding. I suggest you read up more on https://www.debian.org as the scope of this question could keep growing.

Answer (score -1):

Patching a `Software` or a `OS` (Operating System) is exactly an update or a fix for vulnerabilities or a bug. This can increase the performance of the system or fix such bugs which make the system stable from attack.

Some poorly designed patched can sometime introduce new problems.

Comment: Can the `down voter` correct me if I am wrong.